# How to pass through options to newcommand

Tags: macros

I have a command essentially like this:

```
\newcommand\cl[2]{\tikz{\filldraw[fill=#1,...#2] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1cm];}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \cl{blue}{dotted,minimum size=1mm}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Wondering how to take the options like `fill=blue,dotted,minimum size=1mm` and to pass them to a nested function inside `\newcommand`:

```
\filldraw[fill=#1,...#2]
```

**Update** Essentially I'm wondering how to make better use of the options. So from a programming perspective the options are a map like HTML attributes, so `fill=blue,dotted,minimum size=1mm` is really more like:

```
fill=blue,
dotted=dotted,
minimum size=1mm
```

And I wonder two things:

1. How to pass all of them in in bulk, `\filldraw[...#3]` pass in all the options in bulk
2. How to reference an option by key and passing it in. So: `\filldraw[minimum size=#3]`, when there is no '#3' defined. How to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Could you post a MWE of what you currently have, and a minimal example of what you would like to have?

Comment: I essentially just want a find/replace where `\filldraw[fill=#1,...#2]` becomes `\filldraw[fill=blue,dotted,minimum size=1mm]`, without having to specify all the options individually.

Comment: Just have one argument and pass them all within that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan Munn noted, you can use something like

```
\newcommand\cl[2]{%
  \tikz{\filldraw[fill=#1,#2] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1cm];}%
}
```

If you find yourself using the same options frequently, it may be worth defining a new style using `\tikzset`, but it's not entirely clear that's what you're after.

As a metacomment, with some exceptions, TeX's macro replacement is essentially replacing the parameters `#1`, `#2`, ..., `#9` with the arguments to the macro verbatim. Commas aren't special to TeX in any way (by default). So code like `\cl{blue}{dotted,minimum size=1mm}` becomes

```
\tikz{\filldraw[fill=blue,dotted,minimum size=1mm] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1cm];}
```

`pgfkeys`, the mechanism underlying TikZ's option parsing, treats commas as special in that it is looking for a comma-separated list of keys and (optionally) values.